# Sending an image from gmail app lose the extension png

Tags: image, text, android-intent, sendmail

Hi I am trying to share some text and image, I use many snnipes of this forum but nothing works. Mi code is the next one:

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("image/png");
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "testing email send.");

                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.tortilla.patatapro/drawable/" + Integer.toString(R.drawable.ic_home)));             

                startActivity(emailIntent);
```

First it seems that was so easy, but the problem is that when I Share my app with the gmail app and it sends the image and only the subject of the email, then when I open the email the image haven´t got an extension. For example if the image was ic_home.png when I open the email it was something attached with a name like 239378437892 but without extension so the email reader (gmail, hotmail...) doesn´t know what was.

I try to change the code like:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.tortilla.patatapro/drawable/" + R.drawable.ic_home));
```

or

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.tortilla.patatapro/drawable/"+ R.drawable.ic_home + ".png"));
```

But nothing the email from GMAIL app sends the image without extension, and of course the image was a .png extension.

THANKS!